# How can I approach optimization problem convex only into some variables?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, regularization

I have a target function, I've computed its Hessian to check convexity, it has a positive-definite sub-matrix and small negative-definite sub-matrix and a kernel.

I solve material placement optimisation problem. Each variable $w_i$ corresponds to material amount in the i-th node, so each variable is between [0,1] or [0.1, 1] and sum of material is constant, that is $\sum_i w_i = const$.

The current idea is to use convex solvers for convex part, with randomised or brute-force approach for the rest of variables. I also thought about convexifiying the given function, and then tracking backwards from this "fully convex" solution. How those kind of problems is treated in practice? What is state of the art?

Comment: What constraints are involved? How many variables are there? Even if the objective function is not convex you can still find candidates for the solution by solving the first-order conditions.

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. The more details you provide, the more helpful the responses are going to be.

Comment: @smcc thank you for suggestions!

Comment: Can you provide explicit formulas for your objective function and/or constraints? Seeing the structure of the problem can be very helpful in providing a good answer.

Comment: @Alex those are incredibly cumbersome. It comes from FEM simulation of certain elasticity problem, too hairy and too much to type. I always though that convex problems and their relatives are very well thought out, so I can reach out for exiting solver or approach and apply it here.

Comment: You can do a Google search for "sequential convex programming". But my guess, honestly, is that you're not going to find anything useful there. I would suggest that the standard machinery for nonlinear nonconvex optimization (e.g., trust region methods) are as good as you're likely to get.